# Calculating variance in python

Tags: python, variance

I have this code to calculate mean and variance as you input a set of numbers, but my variance is off from what it should be. Is my variance formula off somehow or is it possibly some error in my code?

My output:

```
Input a positive number: 1
mean is  1.0 variance is  0

Input a positive number: 2
mean is  1.5 variance is  0.125

Input a positive number: 3
mean is  2.0 variance is  0.3958333333333333
```

Correct output:

```
Input a positive number: 1
mean is  1.0 variance is  0

Input a positive number: 2
mean is  1.5 variance is  0.5

Input a positive number: 3
mean is  2.0 variance is  0.1
```

```
mean = 0
variance = 0
x = 0
n = 0
while x >= 0:
    x = float(input('Input a positive number: '))  # user input for code
    n += 1
    if x < 0:
        break

    if n == 1:  # Added this if statement to avoid dividing by 0
        mean = x
        print('mean is ', mean, 'variance is ', variance)
    else:
        mean = mean + ((x-mean)/n)  # formula for calculating mean
        variance = (((n-2)/(n-1)) * variance) + (((mean-x)**2)/n)  # formula for calculating variance
        print('mean is ', mean, 'variance is ', variance)
```

Comment: A more usual way, that gives simpler formulas, is to keep track of n, the sum of x and the sum of x^2, and calculate the mean and variance from that.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea thanks! @ThierryLathuille

Comment: FYI I just edited your code to fix the indenting and improve the readability without changing how it works. If you'd like to further clean it up, [here's a gist with a few changes](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/4d16bc14a55684bd5d330c40d64da0f3), like removing some redundancies. Feel free to use it!

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable using a **standard library** function, **Python 3.4+** [has one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.variance). It also does validations required for variance calculations over the number list.

```
from statistics import variance

sample1 = (1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 12) 
print(variance(sample1))
```

**Output:** `15.80952380952381`